# Binary Heap Implemented via a Binary Tree Structure

Tags: java, data-structures

For an assignment, we were instructed to create a priority queue implemented via a binary heap, without using any built-in classes, and I have done so successfully by using an array to store the queued objects. However, I'm interested in learning how to implement another queue by using an actual tree structure, but in doing so I've run across a bit of a problem.

**How would I keep track of the nodes on which I would perform insertion and deletion?** I have tried using a linked list, which appends each node as it is inserted - new children are added starting from the first list node, and deleted from the opposite end. However, this falls apart when elements are rearranged in the tree, as children are added at the wrong position.

**Edit:** Perhaps I should clarify - I'm not sure how I would be able to find the last occupied and first unoccupied leaves. For example, I would always be able to tell the last inserted leaf, but if I were to delete it, how would I know which leaf to delete when I next remove the item? The same goes for inserting - how would I know which leaf to jump to next after the current leaf has both children accounted for?

Answer (score 1):

A tree implementation of a binary heap uses a [complete tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) [or almost full tree: every level is full, except the deepest one]. 

You always 'know' which is the last occupied leaf - where you delete from [and modifying it is O(logn) after it changed so it is not a problem], and you always 'know' which is the first non-occupied leaf, in which you add elements to [and again, modifying it is also O(logn) after it changed].

**The algorithm idea** is simple:

insert: insert element to the first non-occupied leaf, and use [heapify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_operations) [sift up] to get this element to its correct place in the heap.

delete_min: replace the first element with the last occupied leaf, and remove the last occupied leaf. then, heapify [sift down] the heap.

**EDIT:** note that `delete()` can be done to any element, and not only the head, however - finding the element you want to replace with the last leaf will be O(n), which will make this op expensive. for this reason, the `delete()` method [besides the head], is usually not a part of the heap data structure.

Comment: Thanks! However, while I appreciate your prompt answer, it doesn't quite pertain to the issue I have at the moment. I've updated my question above to clarify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to do this for almost a decade.Finally sat down today and wrote it.Anyone who wants it can use it.I got inspired by Quora founder to relearn Heap.Apparently he was asked how would you find K near points in a set of n points in his Google phone screen.Apparently his answer was to use a Max Heap and to store K values and remove the maximum element after the size of the heap exceeds K.The approach is pretty simple and the worst case is nlog K which is better than n^2 in most sorting cases.Here is the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Harish R
 */
public class HeapPractise<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private List<T> heapList;

    public List<T> getHeapList() {
        return heapList;
    }

    public void setHeapList(List<T> heapList) {
        this.heapList = heapList;
    }

    private int heapSize;

    public HeapPractise() {
        this.heapList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.heapSize = heapList.size();
    }

    public void insert(T item) {
        if (heapList.size() == 0) {
            heapList.add(item);
        } else {
            siftUp(item);
        }

    }

    public void siftUp(T item) {
        heapList.add(item);
        heapSize = heapList.size();
        int currentIndex = heapSize - 1;
        while (currentIndex > 0) {
            int parentIndex = (int) Math.floor((currentIndex - 1) / 2);
            T parentItem = heapList.get(parentIndex);
            if (parentItem != null) {
                if (item.compareTo(parentItem) > 0) {
                    heapList.set(parentIndex, item);
                    heapList.set(currentIndex, parentItem);
                    currentIndex = parentIndex;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public T delete() {
        if (heapList.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (heapList.size() == 1) {
            T item = heapList.get(0);
            heapList.remove(0);
            return item;
        }
        return siftDown();
    }

    public T siftDown() {
        T item = heapList.get(0);
        T lastItem = heapList.get(heapList.size() - 1);
        heapList.remove(heapList.size() - 1);
        heapList.set(0, lastItem);
        heapSize = heapList.size();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        while (currentIndex < heapSize) {
            int leftIndex = (2 * currentIndex) + 1;
            int rightIndex = (2 * currentIndex) + 2;
            T leftItem = null;
            T rightItem = null;
            int currentLargestItemIndex = -1;
            if (leftIndex <= heapSize - 1) {
                leftItem = heapList.get(leftIndex);
            }
            if (rightIndex <= heapSize - 1) {
                rightItem = heapList.get(rightIndex);
            }
            T currentLargestItem = null;
            if (leftItem != null && rightItem != null) {

                if (leftItem.compareTo(rightItem) >= 0) {
                    currentLargestItem = leftItem;
                    currentLargestItemIndex = leftIndex;
                } else {
                    currentLargestItem = rightItem;
                    currentLargestItemIndex = rightIndex;
                }
            } else if (leftItem != null && rightItem == null) {
                currentLargestItem = leftItem;
                currentLargestItemIndex = leftIndex;
            }
            if (currentLargestItem != null) {
                if (lastItem.compareTo(currentLargestItem) >= 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    heapList.set(currentLargestItemIndex, lastItem);
                    heapList.set(currentIndex, currentLargestItem);
                    currentIndex = currentLargestItemIndex;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return item;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeapPractise<Integer> heap = new HeapPractise<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            heap.insert(i);
        }
        System.out.println(heap.getHeapList());
        List<Node<Integer>> nodeArray = new ArrayList<>(heap.getHeapList()
                .size());
        for (int i = 0; i < heap.getHeapList().size(); i++) {
            Integer heapElement = heap.getHeapList().get(i);
            Node<Integer> node = new Node<Integer>(heapElement);
            nodeArray.add(node);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeArray.size(); i++) {
            int leftNodeIndex = (2 * i) + 1;
            int rightNodeIndex = (2 * i) + 2;
            Node<Integer> node = nodeArray.get(i);
            if (leftNodeIndex <= heap.getHeapList().size() - 1) {
                Node<Integer> leftNode = nodeArray.get(leftNodeIndex);
                node.left = leftNode;
            }
            if (rightNodeIndex <= heap.getHeapList().size() - 1) {
                Node<Integer> rightNode = nodeArray.get(rightNodeIndex);
                node.right = rightNode;
            }
        }
        BTreePrinter.printNode(nodeArray.get(0));
    }
}

public class Node<T extends Comparable<?>> {
    Node<T> left, right;
    T data;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class BTreePrinter {

    public static <T extends Comparable<?>> void printNode(Node<T> root) {
        int maxLevel = BTreePrinter.maxLevel(root);

        printNodeInternal(Collections.singletonList(root), 1, maxLevel);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<?>> void printNodeInternal(
            List<Node<T>> nodes, int level, int maxLevel) {
        if (nodes.isEmpty() || BTreePrinter.isAllElementsNull(nodes))
            return;

        int floor = maxLevel - level;
        int endgeLines = (int) Math.pow(2, (Math.max(floor - 1, 0)));
        int firstSpaces = (int) Math.pow(2, (floor)) - 1;
        int betweenSpaces = (int) Math.pow(2, (floor + 1)) - 1;

        BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(firstSpaces);

        List<Node<T>> newNodes = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        for (Node<T> node : nodes) {
            if (node != null) {
                String nodeData = String.valueOf(node.data);
                if (nodeData != null) {
                    if (nodeData.length() == 1) {
                        nodeData = "0" + nodeData;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(nodeData);
                newNodes.add(node.left);
                newNodes.add(node.right);
            } else {
                newNodes.add(null);
                newNodes.add(null);
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(betweenSpaces);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 1; i <= endgeLines; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(firstSpaces - i);
                if (nodes.get(j) == null) {
                    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(endgeLines + endgeLines + i
                            + 1);
                    continue;
                }

                if (nodes.get(j).left != null)
                    System.out.print("//");
                else
                    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(1);

                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(i + i - 1);

                if (nodes.get(j).right != null)
                    System.out.print("\\\\");
                else
                    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(1);

                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(endgeLines + endgeLines - i);
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        printNodeInternal(newNodes, level + 1, maxLevel);
    }

    private static void printWhitespaces(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * count; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<?>> int maxLevel(Node<T> node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;

        return Math.max(BTreePrinter.maxLevel(node.left),
                BTreePrinter.maxLevel(node.right)) + 1;
    }

    private static <T> boolean isAllElementsNull(List<T> list) {
        for (Object object : list) {
            if (object != null)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Please note that BTreePrinter is a code I took somewhere in Stackoverflow long back and I modified to use with 2 digit numbers.It will be broken if we move to  3 digit numbers and it is only for simple understanding of how the Heap structure looks.A fix for 3 digit numbers is to keep everything as multiple of 3.
Also due credits to Sesh Venugopal for wonderful tutorial on Youtube on Heap data structure

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PriorityQ<K extends Comparable<K>> {
private class TreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T val;
    TreeNode<T> left, right, parent;
    public String toString() {
        return this.val.toString();
    }
    TreeNode(T v) {
        this.val = v;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
    public TreeNode<T> insert(T val, int position) {
        TreeNode<T> parent = findNode(position/2);
        TreeNode<T> node = new TreeNode<T>(val);
        if(position % 2 == 0) {
            parent.left = node;
        } else {
            parent.right = node;
        }
        node.parent = parent;
        heapify(node);
        return node;
    }
    private void heapify(TreeNode<T> node) {
        while(node.parent != null && (node.parent.val.compareTo(node.val) < 0)) {
            T temp = node.val;
            node.val = node.parent.val;
            node.parent.val = temp; 
            node = node.parent;
        }
    }       
    private TreeNode<T> findNode(int pos) {
        TreeNode<T> node = this;
        int reversed = 1;
        while(pos > 0) {
            reversed <<= 1;
            reversed |= (pos&1);                
            pos >>= 1;
        }
        reversed >>= 1;

        while(reversed > 1) {
            if((reversed & 1) == 0) {
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                node = node.right;
            }
            reversed >>= 1;
        }
        return node;
    }
    public TreeNode<T> remove(int pos) {
        if(pos <= 1) {
            return null;
        }
        TreeNode<T> last = findNode(pos);
        if(last.parent.right == last) {
            last.parent.right = null;
        } else {
            last.parent.left = null;
        }
        this.val = last.val;
        bubbleDown();
        return null;            
    }   

    public void bubbleDown() {
        TreeNode<T> node = this;            
        do {
            TreeNode<T> left = node.left;
            TreeNode<T> right = node.right;
            if(left != null && right != null) {
                T max = left.val.compareTo(right.val) > 0 ? left.val : right.val;
                if(max.compareTo(node.val) > 0) {
                    if(left.val.equals(max)) {
                        left.val = node.val;
                        node.val = max;                         
                        node = left;
                    } else {
                        right.val = node.val;
                        node.val = max;
                        node = right;
                    } 
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else if(left != null) {
                T max = left.val;
                if(left.val.compareTo(node.val) > 0) {
                    left.val = node.val;
                    node.val = max;                         
                    node = left;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while(true);
    }
}
private TreeNode<K> root;
private int position;
PriorityQ(){ 
    this.position = 1;
}
public void insert(K val) {
    if(val == null) {
        return;
    }
    if(root == null) {
        this.position = 1;
        root = new TreeNode<K>(val);
        this.position++;
        return ;
    }
    root.insert(val, position);
    position++;     
}
public K remove() {
    if(root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    K val = root.val;
    root.remove(this.position-1);
    this.position--;
    if(position == 1) {
        root = null;
    }
    return val;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQ<Integer> q = new PriorityQ<>();
    System.out.println(q.remove());
    q.insert(1);
    q.insert(11);
    q.insert(111);
    q.insert(1111);
    q.remove();
    q.remove();
    q.remove();
    q.remove();
    q.insert(2);
    q.insert(4);
}
```

}