# Implement a heap not using an array

Tags: heap, binary-tree

I'm prepping for a Google developer interview and have gotten stuck on a question about heaps. I need to implement a heap as a dynamic binary tree (not array) where each node has a pointer to the parent and two children and there is a global pointer to the root node. The book asks "why won't this be enough?"

How can the standard tree implementation be extended to support heap operations *add()* and *deleteMin()*? How can these operations be implemented in this data structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary Heap Implemented via a Binary Tree Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609047/binary-heap-implemented-via-a-binary-tree-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Can you keep the size of total nodes ? if so, it's easy to know where you should add new element, because that's an almost full tree.

About deleteMin, I think that it will be less effective because you can't access directly to all leaves, as in array (N/2).
You should travel through all paths till you get leaf and then compare them, probably it will cost O(n)